# Android dumpsys cpuinfo output explanation

Tags: android, adb, dumpsys

I am executing the `adb shell dumpsys cpuinfo` command on my android device,

which prints out something like this:

```
2.3% 7398/com.pkg.testapp: 2% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 79 minor
```

Could anyone please explain the meaning of this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing more like reading of /proc// to unravel this look into ProcessCpuTracker.java and later on here [man-proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)